# Error while Embedding Excel sheet into VB.Net Form using Microsoft office spread sheet

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel

I am using Visual studio 2012 & creating a VB.Net Windows Forms Application whereas i am trying to embed an excel sheet data into the form.

I have installed, Office web components 11. while dragging and dropping the Microsoft office spread sheet Item it says following error

> **Failed to import ActiveX control. Please ensure it is properly registered.**
>   PFB snapshot.

**Build console:)**

```
------ Build started: Project: WindowsApplication7, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  COM Reference 'OWC11' is the interop assembly for ActiveX control 'AxOWC11' but was marked to be linked by the compiler with the /link flag. This COM reference will be treated as a reference and will not be linked.
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2015,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "7c0ffab0-cd84-11d0-949a-00a0c91110ed" version 1.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2015,5): error MSB3303: Could not resolve COM reference "0002e558-0000-0000-c000-000000000046" version 1.0. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2015,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "7c0ffab0-cd84-11d0-949a-00a0c91110ed" version 1.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2015,5): error MSB3303: Could not resolve COM reference "0002e558-0000-0000-c000-000000000046" version 1.0. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**Note**: I am able to embed the excel sheet using VBA form in my system.
I am using Microsoft 2010.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you may be able to do your drag/drop, click ok, then rebuild and try to drag/drop again.
If that doesn't work then you may check out this guide from MS [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;249873)

Comment: i have tried many times rebuilding it.. but no luck.. i have now added few logs in the post. please have a look

Comment: Do you have a reference with an error in your "Solution Explorer"?

Comment: I have not added any references in solution explorer. is that a problem

Comment: COM Reference 'OWC11' is the interop assembly for ActiveX control 'AxOWC11' but was marked to be linked by the compiler with the /link flag. This COM reference will be treated as a reference and will not be linked.

Comment: how to run Regsvr32 for this ?

Comment: I would look through the MS reference for registering this then [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;249873)  Hope that helps.